# How to set a button created with css and javascript in close to the top right position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, velo

The button in red with the text inside Button on the top right is a button I can drag from the wix editor it's a built-in button so there is no problem to drag it around and position it.

but then I created my own button, and I can't drag it around to the top right. and it's always a problem and a bit complicated to find the right position because I don't want it on the top right corner but like the red Button close to the top right corner.

This is the code of the button:

```
<div class="btn">
  <div class="part1"></div>
  <div class="part2"></div>
</div>
  
  <style>body, html {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #3498db;
}
.btn {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -32px;
  margin-left: -32px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.btn:active {
  background-color: #c0392b;
}
.part1, .part2 {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/feather/96/591275-arrow-up-64.png);
  background-size: 32px;
  float: left;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
}
.part1 {
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  position: relative;
  top: 32px
}
.part2 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.btn.fullscreen {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.btn.fullscreen .part1 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.btn.fullscreen .part2 {
  transform: rotate(225deg);
}</style>
  
  <script>document.querySelector('.btn').onclick = function () {
  this.classList.toggle('fullscreen');
}</script>
```

The result is the draggable button from wix on the top right and my button is more or less in the center and I want to position my button where the wix button is.

[buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fs0Rr.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the top and right of  .btn css property to control the btn position relative the body

Answer (score 0):

Your button is already `absolute`, just change the `fullscreen` styles to below:

```
.btn.fullscreen {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  top: 9.5%;
  left: 97.5%;
}
```